# Linux Processes

Tags: linux, process

Currently, I am working on a small project and I would much appreciate it if someone could tell me **how can I get the process's info before it dies?** Assuming I have its PID. At the end of the day, **I want to know it's estimated time**... Also is there any possible way to get Google Chrome Tabs **precise PIDS?** (I mean, getting all of it isn't hard but which one is which?)
*Side note:* I used psutil in python for getting (user's all processes)... I have not much experience in Linux

Comment: Is there some kind of event that's thrown before process dies?

Comment: I have just more or less finished an answer _related_ to that topic. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153382/does-stopped-belong-to-blocked-state/547476#547476 It is more about the sideways aspect of managing processes (sleeping). You want to know about the end phase of a process. Maybe that famous "Z" state can lead you a bit.

Comment: Maybe wait for that pidfd, then look for info in /proc. What "estimated time"? You can't know which is which, nobody has this mapping except chrome, unless you really know where exactly chrome stores that mapping and its format and ptrace the chrome main process.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I get the process's info before it dies?

'ps' is the tool for a "snapshot". `top` for a live table. Both have complex man pages. I like `ps axf` which gives a tree structure.

> get Google Chrome Tabs precise PIDS?

The other way round like this you mean? (part (branch) of `ps axf` output)

```
  \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox     
      \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 ...
      \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 ...
      \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 10 ...  
      \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 16 ...  
      \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 17 ...
```

We only see these `childID`. There is no easy way of telling which tab content belongs to which -- unless you keep track yourself by comparing `ps` output before and after opening a browser tab.

These are just technical data. Sometimes very useful. But not meant for user interaction.

If you have a system for experiments in your project, go ahead and send some signals to the pids (not shown) from the command line. But be prepared for the worst - beginning with loosing your bookmarks etc.

Comment: I am sorry I kind of haven't slept 17 hours... I   will Check those tomorrow(mid night here ;) ) and Surely give you an appropriate feedback.

Comment: No hurry. We have a similar here btw ;)

Comment: Good stuff @rastafile. That part "firefox -contentproc ..." Is that a command or output?

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow It is part of ps axf out put edited together - not very elegant. And misleading? I will first aid correct, thx! )I had assumed OQ knows about listing all - "is easy")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but start time and elapsed time can be found with `ps` command.

```
ps -o 'comm,stime,etime' 1134 #1134 is your pid
```

Other options for ps apply of course, like the `-a` option to show other than just the user's processes

Comment: I also think zura has to open up a bit more. "info before it dies?"

Comment: Yeah, i just assumed it meant *before* it dies as opposed to *after* it dies, which would be a more challenging proposition

Comment: What I want is wait before process is at the edge of the death and do that in a manner to not to use while loops. That way I need to check them at every point of time(every 1 or 2minute idk) which consumes lot of power and most likely will drain my laptop battery. If I didn't explain myself or you found it somehow confusing please let me know

Comment: I thought I have clearly defined that estimated time was motsly my interest but other data such as process's names. Also Google Chrome is a pain in my ass... How can i differ process's pids from which tabs it refers to?

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow LOL! btw I just answered, addressing that browser tab thing. Estimated time has three dots and is I think not so clear for all of us. Estimated time of arrival i only know.

Comment: Ah apologies... I want to know how long was app opendish?